# WinUSB_AbortPipe Hangs

Tags: winusb

If I call WinUSB_AbortPipe() just as WinUSB_ReadPipe() starts, I get into a deadlock state. I ran the debug trace log that is provided [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usbcoreblog/archive/2010/02/05/how-to-generate-and-view-a-winusb-debug-trace-log.aspx). Below is the last 5 lines in the log where the problem occurs. I think ReadPipe must have missed the signal, and AbortPipe is waiting for ReadPipe to complete.

```
[0]4E34.4B58::06/09/2015-15:42:12.528 - IOCTL_WINUSB_READ_PIPE
[0]4E34.4B58::06/09/2015-15:42:12.528 - PIPE129: (00000019) The read has been added to the raw io queue
[0]4E34.4B58::06/09/2015-15:42:12.528 - PIPE129: (00000019) The read is being handled
[2]4E34.4ECC::06/09/2015-15:42:12.529 - IOCTL_WINUSB_ABORT_PIPE
[2]4E34.4B58::06/09/2015-15:42:12.529 - PIPE129: (00000019) Reading 64 bytes from the device
```

In my design, I have the IN endpoints read asynchronously into buffers. I found that it is best to set the timeout of the read operation to infinite because the driver hates it when I cause STALLs to occur (ran into other issues with that). So I need to have the disconnect sequence cause the threads to wake up to realize that we need to close. Is there any way to safely do that?

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this is to instead call WinUsb_ResetPipe(). This causes WinUSB_ReadPipe() to unblock, and doesn't seem to lock up as WinUSB_AbortPipe() sometimes does. The only evidence that I have that this works is through successfully running tests over several hours, so I can't guarantee that this is a solution.